# Counting Unique Strings in Tuples, Python

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to count unique strings in a tuple and output only the unique string and its count in a list. I was trying to use list comp., but having some issues:

```
def tupleTag(inputList):
    from collections import Counter

    c = Counter(inputList[0] for inputList in inputList)
    print set(inputList[0], c)

inputList = [('love','family'),('dinner','family','nomnom'),('wedding','romance','love')]
tupleTag(inputList)
```

The correct output would be =

```
[(love,2), (family,2)]
```

Comment: What do you mean unique strings? According to my understanding of unique, there are more *unique* strings in your `inputList` , like `dinner` , `nomnom` , etc. Seems like you mean something else by *unique* , if so, please define it clearly.

Comment: I think madman is referring to duplicate strings.

Comment: @huey yup, I mean duplicate strings.

Comment: @AnandSKumar i mean duplicate strings, like family repeats twice so i want to count those and return one tuple for family with its count.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be on the right track with `collections.Counter`.  I'd also throw in an `itertools.chain`:

```
items = itertools.chain.from_iterable(inputList)
counts = collections.Counter(items)
```

Now you have a map of items to the number of times they appear.  If you want a sorted list of tuples of the form `(<key>, <count>)`, you can use the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method -- And of course, you can filter this to find only strings which are duplicated and their counts:

```
repeated_items = [(key, count) for key, count in counts.most_common() if count > 1]
```

Note, you don't actually *need* the `most_common` to filter the items, but it does give you the results in order of how common the are.  If that isn't necessary, a simple loop over the items would be more efficient:

```
repeated_items = [(key, count) for key, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
```

Comment: what you are saying makes sense, but not familiar with itertools.chain

Comment: Link: `[itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from mgilson is very slick and worth studying. Here's the garden-variety approach using comprehensions:

```
tups   = ...  # Your data.
c      = Counter(x for tup in tups for x in tup)
result = [(k, n) for k, n in c.items() if n > 1]
```

Comment: how does k refer to the strings we counted in the variable c?

Comment: @madman Iterating over the items of counter `c` gives us the word `k` and its count `n`. Beyond that, I'm not sure I follow your precise question.